# Basic responsive design with 1/2 elements per a column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I am stuck with a problem : I want to make very simple "responsive design" for internal news site based on `Sharepoint`. The idea to make show only 1 block per row for small resolutions, and 2 blocks per row for larger resolutions.

I want to do it in this way :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2op6zgccujglcs/4.png

I tried to do it with **Float:left** , but it works bad in that situation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh9wboi131of01l/3.png

Please, help me to find the best solution for this problem.

Comment: You want us to complete your project?

Comment: for block 1, block 2, block 3... just add the width in % and float left; and should work. Very hard to help you if we don't have your code or something

Comment: Post your `HTML` and `CSS`

Comment: You could always just use an already build css library like bootstrap/foundation to aid you.

Comment: That might be a bit overkill, even if you strip it down. You could use a grid system like Skeleton for example.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential questions you're asking:

1) "How do I make the content shift from three columns, to two columns using responsive design?"

and

2) "I'm having trouble with *Content Choreography*...", which is summed up in this article: http://trentwalton.com/2011/07/14/content-choreography/

I'll try to answer question 1, which is basically to use media queries to adjust your layout once it's under 1000px.

Here's an example you would put at the bottom of your stylesheet :

```
@media all and (max-width:999px) {
   .yourDiv { 
      float: none; 
      width: 100%;
   }
   .yourOtherDiv { 
      float: none; 
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

This is the general idea anyway. You tell your floated divs to stop floating so they stack on top of eachother in a tunnel of content.

Question #2 is a little trickier to explain if that is what you were asking.

If you post your code, I would be happy to try and help more specifically.